# calendar and text not coming in a single row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have created an html stuff using bootstrap 2.3.2. The html content is rendering but the issue is that the calendar and text is coming in different row also the calendar css is breaking.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j40bkpc9/)**

**html**

```
<div class="box-content">
    <li><a href="#"> <span class="mycalendar"> <strong>NOV</strong> <span>20</span>
        </span></a>
        <strong>Name:</strong> <a href="#">Test </a><br> <strong>Since:</strong>
        17/05/2012<br> <strong>Status:</strong> <span
        class="label label-success">Approved</span></li>
</div>
```

My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float:left` for getting your desire situation.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/j40bkpc9/2/)

**Edited after comment:**

For centering the element, you can use `display:inline-block;` and then wrap other elements by a span.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/j40bkpc9/7/)

Comment: Actually I want it at center

Comment: but still in the fiddle it is aligned on left

Comment: Nope, I need everything at the center of box-content

Comment: @AlexMan Give `text-align:center;` to the `li`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/j40bkpc9/10/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97655/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-alex-man).